# Выпадающие меню по клику (без JS)

Tags: html, css, меню

Здравствуйте,

Мне нужно сделать выпадающие меню по клику использую только HTML/CSS. В принципе, я его создал, но есть проблема в том что я не использую **id**, а без него не получилось.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать [такой вариант меню](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzGVNy) без использования **id**?

Спасибо!

Код **HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <label for="checkbox"><img src="http://placehold.it/59x59" width="59" height="59" alt="Icon of menu"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#">Страница</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Страница</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Страница</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Во-первых, добавьте весь нужный HTML и CSS прямо в вопрос; ссылки на всякие кодепены здесь типа запрещены, потому что могут отвалиться в будущем. Во-вторых, без js такое вряд ли можно сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
label {cursor: pointer;}
ul {list-style: none;}
.list {display: none;}
.checkbox {display: none;}

.checkbox:checked ~ .list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label class="checkbox1"><img src="http://placehold.it/59x59" width="59" height="59" alt="Icon of menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
 
    <ul class="list">  
      <li><a href="#">Страница</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Страница</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Страница</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </label>
</nav>
```

не самий лутший вариант но я думаю подойдет

Родственные селекторы по своему поведению похожи на соседние селекторы (запись вида E + F), но в отличие от них стилевые правила применяются ко всем близлежащим элементам. К примеру, для селектора h1~p стиль будет применяться ко всем элементам

, располагающихся после заголовка . При этом  и

должны иметь общего родителя, так что если

вставить внутрь , то стили применяться уже не будут.

Comment: А почему не лучший вариант?

Comment: я уверен что можна зделать и попроще но я пока незнаю как))